# Trying to log in a logged-in user on Facebook returns an error instead of redirecting back

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want users to log into Facebook before they can access certain content on my website. The code works fine when the users are logged out of Facebook. They are shown a button that sends them to Facebook to log in, then redirects them back to my site.

Until a few days ago, the code also worked when they were already logged in. Logged in users also saw the login buttion, but when they clicked it, they immediately got directed back to my site, without having to interact with Facebook at all. Now, when they are already logged in, they see a Facebook error page (with the URL https://www.facebook.com/common/invalid_request.php):

[image: Sorry, your request could not be processed. Please try again]

I use the Facebook PHP SDK version 5, and this is the relevant part of my code. "APP_ID" and "APP_SECRET" are the correct strings in the live code, of course.

```
require_once( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/facbookphpsdk/autoload.php' );

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
    'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
    'default_access_token' => 'APP_ID|APP_SECRET'
]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo "1<br>";
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo "2<br>";
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {

    // user is logged in to Facebook

} else {

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['public_profile']; // optional
    $callback = 'http://my.website.com/login_to_facebook.php';
    $loginurl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);

    // show a login dialog for the user to log in to Facebook

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with my code at all.

For some reason unrelated to the Facebook login, I had provided the login URL as the action of a form and sent the user to the Facebook login page by submitting that form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $loginurl; ?>" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="Facebook">Log in with Facebook</button>
</form>
```

Until some time last week this has worked fine, and it still works for users who are not logged in to Facebook. For some reason it no longer works for logged in users now.

I solved the problem, by providing the login URL as a link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $loginurl; ?>">Log in with Facebook</a>
```

This now works with logged-in as well as logged-out users.